# function does not make it past else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Why is my pastPres function not working? It is supposed to change the color for a time block in a calendar depending on whether that block is in the past present or future.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".saveBtn").on("click", function () {
        var description = $(this).siblings(".description").val();
        var time = $(this).parent().attr("id")
        localStorage.setItem(time, description)
    })

    function pastPres() {
        var blockTime = moment().hour()
        $(".time-block").each(function () {
            var time = $(this).attr("id")
            if (time < blockTime) {
                $(this).addClass("past")
            } else if(time > blockTime) {
                $(this).removeClass("past")
                $(this).addClass("future")
            } else {
               $(this).removeClass("future")
               $(this).addClass("present")
            }
        })
    }
 
    pastPres()

    var interval = setInterval(pastPres, 15000)

    $("#9am .description").val(localStorage.getItem("9am"))
    $("#10am .description").val(localStorage.getItem("10am"))
    $("#11am .description").val(localStorage.getItem("11am"))
    $("#12pm .description").val(localStorage.getItem("12pm"))
    $("#1pm .description").val(localStorage.getItem("1pm"))
    $("#2pm .description").val(localStorage.getItem("2pm"))
    $("#3pm .description").val(localStorage.getItem("3pm"))
    $("#4pm .description").val(localStorage.getItem("4pm"))
    $("#5pm .description").val(localStorage.getItem("5pm"))
    $("#currentDay").text(moment().format("MMMM DD, YYYY"))

})
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What do you expect it to do vs what is at actually doing?

Comment: And what steps have you tried to debug it such as looking at the specific values within it?

Comment: If your `.time-block` elements have `id` values like `9am`, `10am`, etc, you realise that's not going to compare well to number values like `9`, `10`, etc which is what you get from `moment().hour()`

Comment: You are comparing strings. You need to compare time values instead

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings. You need to compare time values instead. Since you are using moment you can invoke a new moment instance for the time and let it handle parsing to military time:

```
function pastPres() {
    var blockTime = moment().hour();
    $(".time-block").each(function () {
        var time = moment($(this).attr("id"), ["hA"]).hour()
        if (time < blockTime) {
            $(this).addClass("past")
        } else if(time > blockTime) {
            $(this).removeClass("past")
            $(this).addClass("future")
        } else {
           $(this).removeClass("future")
           $(this).addClass("present")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `.time-block` elements are the same as `#9am`, `#10am`, etc, it appears you're trying to compare a string to a number like

```js
'9am' < 10
```

which as far as JavaScript is concerned, is `false`.

I suggest you add some better data to your elements like

```html
<div id="9pm" data-hour="21" class="time-block">
```

and use

```js
const time = $(this).data('hour')
```